# Why is an NSString 'forgetting' what it is?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I was hoping for some help to understand why I need to re-cast my variable when it is a string from the start.

Here's the code:

```
+ (BOOL)hasOperandComponents:(NSString *)operandToTest
{
    NSArray *componentsOfOperand = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",operandToTest] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    if (componentsOfOperand.count>1) return YES; return NO;
}
```

If I don't use the embedded call to 'stringWithFormat' then I get the rather common error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have been able to find answers to what this error means and hence how to avoid it (see my code above) by searching other Q's and A's... but no good explanation as to why my operandToTest seems to 'forget' that it is a NSString and become an _NSCFNumber.

I'm suspicious that it is because this is a Class method... but why would that matter when a specific instance of NSString *operandToTest is passed to the class method?

Please help?

Comment: Are you completely certain that operandToTest is really an NSString, and you aren't passing an NSNumber somewhere? Also, have you tried running with zombies enabled?

Comment: You can stop in the debugger and do `print operandToTest`. It should say something like `$1 = (NSNumber*)0x12345678` or `$1 = (NSString*)0x12345678`. That will tell you what the object actually is.

Comment: Well it is true that sometimes the value passed in is a number. I'm eating through an id *NSarray of numbers, operators and variables but the variable I pass in has been set as follows:
   'NSString *secondOperand = [self descriptionOfTopOfStack:stack];'
So haven't I already cast everything to be a String?

Comment: Oh and I have seen Zombie mentioned but haven't tried to use it yet - I guess that will be my next set of web searches!
Thanks for the response!

Comment: I just did the debugger thing - and get ' $1 = (NSString *) 0xbd31ae0'

Comment: Can you show `descriptionOfTopOfStack`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you don't have a string to begin with. The value that you're passing into the method as `operandToTest` is, in fact, an `NSNumber*`. You need to look at the calling function to figure out why this is.

Comment: Yep I was proof reading my calling function as part of an update to my post so you could help figure out the problem... when I saw that I was indeed introspecting my array element to see if it was a number and directly setting it to the variable I pass in - rather than casting it from NSNumber to NSString as I was mentally thinking I did - Opps

Now to see if I can 'fix' the issue in my caller :-)

Comment: @user1215012: You can't "cast" it from `NSNumber` to `NSString` anyway. That's actually what you did when you passed it to the function. Casting doesn't change the object, it just changes what the compiler thinks the object is. What you need to do is convert it using the method of your choice.

Comment: Yep that fixed it - Thank you Kevin and Catfish_Man so much... Opps not cast... I used introspection to confirm i was dealing with an NSNumber and then (the new part) actually converted it using stringWithFormat :-)